# Connection string in web config to connect to EC2 Sql Server from local computer

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core-mvc, connection-string

My application runs perfectly on my local computer however the database i am willing to use is on an instance in EC2 which i am issues connecting to the database.

i do have an Elastic IP associate with my instance and open the port 1433 in my security group. i also enable to the TCP protocol in SQL SERVER and created a new inbound rule in my firewall but still unable to connect to the database.

i am also unsure that the connection string is correct but cannot figure out the right solution to the problem

> Connection String

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();


        var connection = @"server=example.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=False;User ID=user;Password=user";
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    }
```

Comment: can you connect to the DB through SQL management studio? That way we can know if its the network or the config http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToMicrosoftSQLServerInstance.html

Comment: @Alander i think its a web config after doing these step im getting these : "cannot connect to example.eu.westetc... and  Login failed for user...

Comment: Try replacing the server name with the elastic IP and see if that works

Comment: Refer to the guide : https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/using-aws-database-rds-with-microsoft-mvc